# Computational complexity of sampling from discrete and continuous distributions?

Tags: probability, distributions, sampling, density-function, time-complexity

What is the computational complexity of sampling from any of these cases? I mean the computational complexity of the most efficient existing algorithm, not a possible algorithm or a lower bound.

1. Finite discrete probability distribution $p_1, ..., p_N$:
   I think this is $O(\log N)$. I tested sampling using python function `np.random.choice` and the log plot was linear. Also, I think this is true based on this paper:
   https://people.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~kbringma/paper/2012ICALP.pdf
2. A continuous distribution with closed-form pdf and CDF, for example, exponential distribution.
   From python implementation, it seems to be $O(1)$ but I'm not sure how to test that.
3. A continuous distribution with closed-form pdf while CDF is not closed form, for example, normal distribution. It seems to be $O(1)$

What about sampling from truncated versions of these distributions? Could anyone also suggest reference/references on this topic?

Comment: O(1) for discrete distributions: see https://www.keithschwarz.com/darts-dice-coins/ for a very nice discussion.

Comment: The complexity depends on the algorithm.  A *huge* number of algorithms are extant, with many specialized algorithms developed for various distributional families.